# Updating button click event in android app through DataChange class in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm a newbie in android and firebase development. I have been working on saving my app's button in firebase and retrieving them. My java coding is little weak.
My concept is: when the user clicks on the button in app that clicked button's status should be updated in the other phone with the same app.

I have been able to save the button status:

[this link is for my database structure figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TkPd.png)
the code I used to store is:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            String onoff="";
            HashMap<String,Object> Update = new HashMap<>();
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.living_btn:
                    if (click ==0){
                        click=1;
                        onoff = "/SWITCH-01=ON";
                        Update.put("clicked",onoff);
                        buttons.child("living_btn").updateChildren(Update);
                        living_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.livingroom);
                    }else{
                        click=0;
                        onoff = "/SWITCH-01=OFF";
                        Update.put("clicked",onoff);
                        buttons.child("living_btn").updateChildren(Update);
                        living_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.livingroom_off);
                    }
                    break;
```

I want to retrieve the data from the database, so I created separate classes for each buttons. Then used the following code to call them in main activity:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Buttons");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
Log.e("data",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

Buttons buttonEntity = dataSnapshot.getValue(Buttons.class);

}

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

but I'm unable to retrieve the data is the way I have chosen the datachange class is correct? Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Show the reference of "database". database.getReference("Buttons")

Comment: @rasi i didn't get you.

Comment: @Rasi the "Buttons" is the parent node of the data base which stores all the other buttons values as child, it was create as "buttons = FirebaseDatabase. getReference("Buttons")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use correct Reference of Node.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Buttons");
```

Collect status of all Buttons like this in `ValueEventListener`-

```
final HashMap<String, Boolean> status = new HashMap<>();
    for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        status.put(childSnapShot.getKey(), childSnapShot.child("clicked").getValue(Boolean.class));
}
```